# Перемножить элементы таблицы jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, арифметика

Есть корзина интернет магазина, в которой стараюсь сделать перерасчет по клику цены.
В случае 1 товара проблем особых нет, но в случае 2х и более товаров он считает только же 1 элемент и разбрасывает его на все остальные.
Есть таблица с классом  jshop td цена за единице товара с класом single-price-var, но поскольку там есть буквы я извлекаю цифру вот так:

```js
var oldPricecart = jQuery('.single-price-var').text();
    var workintoldpricecart = parseInt(oldPricecart);
```

Количество (можно менять по клику)

```js
var quantity = jQuery('.data>.inputbox').val();
```

Подсумма в каждой tr за товар -td с классом total_price.
Ну и на выходе  отдельно строка  для суммы по всем товарам с классом.

Суть вопроса следующая, каким образом можно перебрать все элементы таблицы с товарами (пересчитать) по клику на плюс или минус количества какого-либо товара чтобы все это на выходе записать в общую сумму.

Пробовал each, но скорей либо я торможу или же не туда смотрю.

Comment: Исходя из чего цена товаров в корзине "вытягивается" из HTML элементов? По каким причинам нельзя использовать JS объект и на его основе генерировать визуальное представление корзины? 
P.S.: для лучшего понимания добавьте воспроизводимый пример, используя для этого кнопку "Фрагмент кода" `Ctrl + M`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Весь товар
// тут задача пробижаться по всем элементав таблицы, в каждой узнать ценну и сложить.
$('#all').on('click', function(){
  // создаём 0, она будет общем значением
  let total_price = 0;
  // проходим по всем товарам
  $('.basket .item').each(function(){
    // получаем текущую ценну
    let this_price =  parseInt($(this).find('.total_price').text());
    // прибавляем её к тому общему значению
    total_price = total_price + this_price;
  });
  // в конце выводим результат
  $('.basket_price b').text(total_price);
});

// Выделенный
// тут почти всё тоже самое, только проверим "состояние" выбранного чекбокса, если не выбран, то пропускаем
$('#selected').on('click', function(){
  // так же нулевая переменная
  let total_price = 0;
  // так же пробегаем по всем элементам
  $('.basket .item').each(function(){
    // а вот тут уже основное, проверка на нажат ли checkbox
    let isSelected = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked');
    if(isSelected) {
      let this_price =  parseInt($(this).find('.total_price').text());
      total_price = total_price + this_price;
      }
    });
  $('.basket_price b').text(total_price);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="basket">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="name">
        Какой-то товар 1
        <input type="checkbox" checked>
    </div>
    <div class="total_price">100</div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="name">
        Какой-то товар 2
        <input type="checkbox" checked>
    </div>
    <div class="total_price">200</div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="name">
        Какой-то товар 3
        <input type="checkbox" checked>
    </div>
    <div class="total_price">300</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="basket_price">
  Вся корзина стоит <b>100500</b>
</div>
<b>Пересчитать:</b><br>
<input id="all" type="button" value="Весь товар">
<input id="selected" type="button" value="Только выбранное">
```